# Python socket issue when connecting to raspberry pi

Tags: python, sockets, port

I am trying to do wireless communications between a PC (windows) and a Raspberry Pi 3 using python's socket module. The server is the PC and the client is the Pi. When I run the code (server first then client) both scripts get stuck after "hey, checking TCP socket".

When I do the reverse (Pi being the server and PC being the client) the code works fine, with data been sent correctly.

Both the PC and Pi are connected to the same network. The IP address of PC is 10.0.0.198 and the Pi is 10.0.0.63.

I think the problem is that the port is not open when I use my PC as a server. How to resolve this?

My client script:

```
import socket
import sys

def read(port):
        s = socket.socket()
        host = '10.0.0.198' #(IP address of PC (server))
        s.connect((host,port))
        try:
                msg = s.recv(1024)
                s.close()
    except socket.error, msg:
            sys.stderr.write('error %s'%msg[1])
            s.close()
            print 'close'
            sys.exit(2)
    return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 1025
    while True:
            print 'hey, checking TCP socket'
            data = read(port)
            print 'i just read %s' % data
            print 'port num is: %d' % port
            port = port + 1
```

My server script:

```
import socket
import time

def send(data, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Got connection from',addr
    c.send(data)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 1025
    num = 1
while True:
            print 'hey, sending data'
            words = 'helloWorld'
            data = words + str(num)
            print 'send data: %s' % data
            send(data,port)
            port = port + 1
            num = num + 1
```

Comment: Based entirely on your diagnosis, disable temporarily your PC firewall and re-test. If it works, enable it and search on how to open the port you are using in your firewall, it depends on the OS system and version,  or maybe on your AV if it has a FW replacing the OS one. Trouble with OS or FW configuration is not much adequate to ask in stackoverflow. More to superuser or serverfault.